# Is an inflection point of an algebraic cuve intrinsic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

On an algebraic curve $C$ in $P^2$ over a field $F$, a regular point $p\in C$ is called an inflection point if $I(p,C\cap L)>2$, where $L$ is the tangent line through $p$. I'm wondering is this concept independent of isomorphism? We know that it's invariant under projective maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A smooth curve $C$ of genus one admits the structure of an algebraic group 
 [(elliptic  curve)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve). In particular, one can translate by points on $C$; therefore, an inflection point can be translated to any other point of $C$, and the notion is not independent of isomorphism.